# Undefined symbol errors showing in Xcode when trying to use Objective-C libraries in Swift project

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, flutter, dart

I was using Objective-C libraries in my flutter project which supports Swift. I am using a Bridging file for importing the Objective-C frameworks. So, during building I have encountered some issues which are shown below. Is anyone aware of these errors?

```
Undefined symbol: _av_bsf_alloc

Undefined symbol: _av_bsf_get_by_name

Undefined symbol: _av_bsf_receive_packet

Undefined symbol: _av_bsf_send_packet

Undefined symbol: _avcodec_receive_frame

Undefined symbol: _avcodec_send_packet
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors are indicating that the symbols you are trying to use in your `Objective-C` code are not being found at runtime. These symbols are part of the [FFmpeg library](https://ffmpeg.org/). It seems that your project is not linking against the `FFmpeg library` correctly.